# Dynamic Method with Fragments

Tags: java, android, object, android-fragments, methods

I am creating an application and use a DrawerActivity.
This DrawerActivity has the **onNavigationItemSelected()** method.
The question I have is, can I create a method like

```
public void select(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = menuActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();
}
```

Therefore I would only pass the desired Fragment. In the past I used to have houndreds of lines of code and want to change this now. It is a flexible method I wish to create if you want so. The example above does not work because it expects a clear object, but I hope you get the point of my question.

Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: Can't you simply create the fragment instance based on the id sent to the onNavigationItemSelected() and call the select method?

Comment: I got a lot of fragments and want to reduce code

Answer (score 0):

You will always need to map every menu item id to a specific fragment.

In order to avoid long switch case statements you could use a design pattern like [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) with reflection.

Some sample code

```
public class FragmentFactory {
    private Map<Integer, Class<? extends Fragment>> menuItemFragments;

    public FragmentFactory() {
        menuItemFragments = new HashMap<>();
        menuItemFragments.put(R.id.fragment_main, MainFragment.class);
        menuItemFragments.put(R.id.fragment_about, AboutFragment.class);
        menuItemFragments.put(R.id.fragment_settings, SettingsFragment.class);
    }

    public Fragment getFragmentById(int menuItemId) {
        Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass = menuItemFragments.get(menuItemId);
        if(fragmentClass == null) throw new NullPointerException("fragment not found");
        try {
            return fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed to construct fragment", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Than in onNavigationItemSelected you do the following:

```
 private FragmentFactory mFragmentFactory = new FragmentFactory();

 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment = mFragmentFactory.getFragmentById(menuItem.getItemId());
        select(fragment);

        return true;
 }
```

Comment: But therefore I would always need to know the position of fragment in the hashmap right?

Comment: No because it is mapped with the menu item id. Simply use the getFragmentById method to get the fragment which belongs to the menu item.